# My webpage is showing strange url on google results

Tags: google, domains, wordpress, url

I'm developing a website for a local school on Wordpress but today noticed someting weird when I look for the page in google this is the result I get:

KEELER FORCE ブラック+Creepy Crawler M8090 7.00-16 4本 ...
www.cudec.edu.mx › 激安セール
Traducir esta página
ホーム > 激安セール > KEELER FORCE ブラック+Creepy Crawler M8090 7.00-16 4本 [ジムニー JB64W/JB23W/JA系(JA11V/JA71V等)] キーラーフォース グロスブラック+マキシス Creepy Crawler M8090 16X5.5J+22 5/139.7 送料無料. TOYOTIRES ...

The url/domain is https://www.cudec.edu.mx / cudec.edu.mx

What's happening how can I fix it?

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

Your website has been **hacked**. If you check the source page in a browser, you'll find a lot of spam and porn links by the end of the page:

```
<p style="overflow: auto; position: fixed; height: 0pt; width: 0pt">
<a href="(hidden)" title="izmir escort" rel="dofollow">izmir escort</a>
<a href="(hidden)" title="hd vr porn" rel="dofollow">hd vr porn</a>
<a href="(hidden)" title="power plus macun">power plus macun</a>
<a href="(hidden)" title="penimed">penimed</a>
<a href="(hidden)" title="penijel">penijel</a>
<a href="(hidden)" title="amaranth �ay&#305;">amaranth �ay&#305;</a>
<a href="(hidden)" title="chocolate slim">chocolate slim</a>
</p>
```

You need to patch up your installation, check your whole site, and clean everything up..